# My unity app keeps using more and more ram until it crashes after loading lots of external images

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, ram

I have a unity app, that should have been made in winforms, but I used unity, bc. The app loads external images, if they exist. the problem is that unity keeps using more and more ram until it crashes. I know its the images because I added a feature to turn off image loading, and that fixed the problem, I need help getting my app to stop using so much ram!!

here is the code I used, (its all not mine)

```
StartCoroutine("FindImage");

public IEnumerator FindImage()
{
    var a = FolderLocationPath;
    /*
    while (!Main.EnableSelected)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }*/
    try
    {
        ModViewImage.sprite = LoadNewSprite(a + @"\preview.jpg");
    }
    catch
    {
        try
        {
            ModViewImage.sprite = LoadNewSprite(a + @"\preview.png");
        }
        catch 
        { 
            Debug.LogWarning("--No-Image--" + a.Replace(Main.GetMain.FolderPath, "")); 
        }
    }
    yield return null;
}


public Sprite LoadNewSprite(string FilePath, float PixelsPerUnit = 0.01f)
{

    // Load a PNG or JPG image from disk to a Texture2D, assign this texture to a new sprite and return its reference

    Texture2D SpriteTexture = LoadTexture(FilePath);
    Sprite NewSprite = Sprite.Create(SpriteTexture, new Rect(0, 0, SpriteTexture.width, SpriteTexture.height), new Vector2(0, 0), PixelsPerUnit);

    return NewSprite;
}




public Texture2D LoadTexture(string FilePath)
{

    // Load a PNG or JPG file from disk to a Texture2D
    // Returns null if load fails

    Texture2D Tex2D;
    byte[] FileData;

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath))
    {
        FileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
        Tex2D = new Texture2D(1, 1);           // Create new "empty" texture
        if (Tex2D.LoadImage(FileData))
        {
            Tex2D.anisoLevel = 1;
            Tex2D.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
            Tex2D.Apply();
            return Tex2D;
        }            // If data = readable -> return texture
    }
    return null;                     // Return null if load failed
}
```

Comment: Could there be a need for the using construct? Also what's the idea with trying the Load and then trying again if it throws?

Comment: Update, setting the ui interface to inactive/disabled freezes the ram consumption, but re-enabling it un-freezes the ram consumption

Comment: Why is `FindImage` an `IEnumerator` if you always return a single null value? How are you calling this method?

Comment: @Carlos different image (png - jpg)

Comment: @Compufreak `StartCoroutine("FindImage");`

Comment: Are you by any chance doing something like this? 
`Care must be taken when starting a coroutine in periodic functions like Update, LateUpdate, FixedUpdate etc. because you can crowd the memory with thousands of coroutines executing in parallel - the frame rate drops like a rock, and Unity may even crash when enough coroutines are stealing CPU time and memory.`

[Source](https://answers.unity.com/questions/357783/startcoroutine.html)

Comment: @Compufreak `the co-routine gets called on creation, and depending on your computer that can be upwards of 100+`
using normal methods makes the frame rate drop like a rock so i tried to use the co-routines, and it helped quite a bit, but i dont get it bc they stop after they run once

Comment: On creation of what? I guess you mean it can be upwards of 100+ times / objects created? 
In that case you should make sure each texture file gets only loaded once and is cached in something like a static dictionary. You should also monitor the amount of calls to this method to make sure you are not executing it in an endless loop by accident.

Comment: Pretty sure your coroutine is running every frame and loading the exact same image every frame 'ModViewImage.sprite = LoadNewSprite(a + @"\preview.jpg");'

Comment: I have quadruple check guys, co-routine gets run once and once only.
when the gui prefab it created it gets run once, and once only

Comment: upon further investigation it seems the issue maybe another co-routine, not sure though. 

`does not seem like it...`
`no im 99% sure the other one is not the problem`

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that anymore - you might need to attach the debugger and try to find the real issue by stepping through your code where possible, or set multiple breakpoints and watch inbetween which breakpoints memory usage starts to grow to narrow down the issue. I don't think it's an undisposed file stream as ReadAllBytes should not keep anything open, and I don't see anything else wrong (not an unity expert) with the code you provided.

Comment: I have changed all of the co-routines to void's now, still have the same issue, even in the unity editor, not just the build (it was always like this, just wanted to clarify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my personal opinion; the First thing you should always do when you encounter a memory/performance problem, is *use the profiler*.

There you will be able to see what is actually eating up all your RAM, and with the CPU profiler you can see garbage collection allocation to see if there are any suspects there.

I would suggest in the future to use the profiler as soon as you encounter a similar problem.
That being said, from the code you did include I don't think it's possible to tell where your problem is for certain.

Some general suggestions:

1. If you do not need to have read/write access to the texture data/pixels, send `false` in the 2nd parameter of `Texture2D.LoadTexture` in order to mark it as non-readable; this in effect lowers 50% of the RAM consumption per texture loaded into memory, and is only needed if you manipulate/read data from the texture.
2. From the usage of the legacy `LoadTexture` function, I think you are running on Unity 5.3 or so; I would strongly recommend updating your Unity to a more... from the current decade, which will most likely improve your performance overall, and address various memory leaks in the engine that might be causing this.
3. Everything in managed code needs to be dereferenced when you are done with it; if you are loading theses images and keeping a reference somewhere, they will not be freed from memory and this might also be a reason for your problem.

Comment: I am using Unity 2019.4.0f1 (LTS)

Comment: Do you know of a better way of loading external images?

Comment: LoadTexture is my own function